# How to disable 3rd party cookies in Java/Selenium for the last (121) version of Chrome/FF

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

Can't set the "Block third-party cookies" option for the last version of the Chrome Driver for my autotests.

Every time the new "instance" of Chrome is opened with a basic settings of cookies.
ChatGPT proposed different options around "profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies", 2", but I believe this is something about the previos version of Chrome. As minimum it haven't help also.

option 1:

```
`public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
    prefs.put("profile.block_third_party_cookies", true);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
   
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://shop.mercedes-benz.com/en-au/shop/vehicle/srp/demo?sort=relevance-demo&assortment=vehicle");
}`
```

option 2:

```
`public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--block-third-party-cookies");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://shop.mercedes-benz.com/en-au/shop/vehicle/srp/demo?sort=relevance-demo&assortment=vehicle");
}`
```